# How to render certain edges

Tags: rendering, edges, freestyle, npr

I been looking for this everywhere online and still found no answer. I'm trying to find a way to use freestyle but it slows my render down. How can I use freestyle for certain edges while not rendering the rest of the mesh at all. Like seams almost I just don't even want the render to even see the rest of the mesh. All I want is the outline of certain edges to render quickly. I also have most settings in render tab set low.

Right now I have a cube with outline rendering at 0.15  to  0.20

My question is if there's a way to mark edges to get rendered while the rest of the mesh doesn't even get seen, I think that will speed up the render exponentially.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of it?

Answer (score 4):

You may use the ***Edge Mark*** option of the *Freestyle* to define what edges would be rendered.
[image]

Enable *Freestyle* renderer in *Render* header-->*Freestyle* panel. Set the line thickness as you like.
[image]

Select the edges you want the *Freestyle* to render, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>-->*Mark Freestyle Edge* to make them renderable.
[image]

In *Render Layers* header-->*Freestyle Line Set* panel check the ***Edge Mark*** checkbox. Uncheck the *Silhouette*, *Border* and *Crease* checkboxes to make the contour of the object renderless. 
[image]

Here's the render result:
[image]

You can go further and render only selected edges. With the vertices/edges selected in *Edit Mode* duplicate them with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and make them a separate object (<kbd>P</kbd>-->*Selection*). Move the original object to another layer and hit render. 
[image]

Here's the result:
[image]

Not sure if it is what you're looking for. Let me know if I helped you.

***UPDATE:*** If you want to render only the edges give the object a *Transparent* shader in *Cycles*. The *Freestyle* settings should stay the same as in the examples above.
[image]

Comment: Thanks that helps with the edges a lot :D but it still renders the rest of the mesh. I know I can go into passes and uncheck combined and Z but it still looks for the mesh. How can it care about just the marked edges and not focus at all on the rest of the mesh?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Hope this is the solution you're looking for.

Comment: As an addition to render only edges of the object drawn with Freestyle you can disable rendering surfaces by unchecking *Use Surfaces* under Render Layers tab. This will bypass rendering materials and significantly speed up rendering of the scene.